# Calculating biggest possible bid when fees apply

Tags: calculus

I want to buy something and I need to specify my bid as a value before fees of 0.1% are applied. The bid must be no more than 8 decimal places.

What formula should I apply to place a bid that maximizes my capital?

I know that if I have `1` I could bid `0.99900099`, pay fees of `0.00099900099` and have `0.00000000901`left over.

I tried `Capital.multipliedBy(0.999).RoundedTo(8)` but that gives me an incorrect maximum bid of `0.999`.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, $\frac 1{1+.001}=0.999000999000999\cdots$ so your number must be less than that.  Just cutting it to $8$ digits gives us $0.99900099$ as your best bet.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I'm having one of those days where my brains is working at 1/10th capacity.

Comment: Also I was using bignumber.js which was giving me a different output for `new BigNumber(1).dividedBy(new BigNumber(1).plus(0.001)).toFixed(8)`